# How do I bring up the page where I write Python program, compile and run it, and see the output?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

Sorry if my questions are extremely stupid, but I'm quite at a loss while trying to use Python from Ubuntu Linux. My friend installed the Pycharm for me. I can go without using any commands, to files-->Pycharm projects---> click on one project and see the files, which I can open.

But I'm lost as of how to **compile** and **run the files** and ***see* the output at this step**? The .py files saved before (written with hello world and some really simple ones) are opening, but ***how* can I see the output**?

Also, when I go to the programs by files-->Pycharm projects---> file1.py, file 2.py...etc., do we code and run them from the terminal, using the Linux features? If not, how can I do all of the coding and running from the terminal?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean but "how can I do all of the coding and running from the terminal?" you can use nano to edit to code and run the code on the terminal too 
see this link to know more about nano : [HERE](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/)